# eclipse auto-compile only creates packages- not class files

Tags: java, eclipse, build, auto-compile

I am not sure what happened. I have done the following to troubleshoot:
verify the buildpath has no errors
unchecked "abort build when buildpath error occurs"
set "incomplete buildpath" and "circular dependencies " to warning from error
verified that there are no exclusions.

This has me stumped. 
The only thing i did was synchronize with the svn repo, and I use subversive plugin

Answer (score 3):

one of the possible reason can be that your project does not have 'Java Builder'... to check it go to the

```
Project Preferences > Builders
```

here you see all builders of the project, do you have here `'Java Builder'` checked? if you don't, then in best case you can try to press 'New...' and choose it there; otherwise you can open `.project` file and in block `<buildSpec> .. </buildSpec>` add the following:

```
<buildSpec>
    ...
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
    ...
</buildSpec>
```

after Eclipse reloading you will see Java Builder and it should compile your classes.

But this is what typically happens to me ;) Otherwise check your builders, maybe take a look at 'Project Natures' in project preferences (`obj.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature` should be at least checked).

Just hope it solves your issue

Comment: org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder and org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.builder - this is a brand new project. Is there a way to turn up the debug levels on the java builder ? looks like the builders are being run because i get compile errors and markers, just no .class files show up in the workspace

Comment: @mafalda: I don't knwo about debug levels.. you can check `workspace/.metadata/.log` file, and look if there i any exception thrown by Eclipse. Btw, shown in workspace (in Eclipse), or you don't see them on file system?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to clean the project? Eclipse allow to clean the build state (i.e. remove all classes etc. and create them again). It can help in such situations.

Note that the Eclipse Java compiler is an incremental compiler. I don't know it deeply, but some metafiles might be wrong and the Eclipse compiler can think that everything has been compiled.

Answer (score 0):

ok. I found that the .class files are indeed being generated, but not visible in the navigator view due to setup filtering out .class files. This was not the case before so I am thinking its either change to the eclipse default setting or something that happened with a svn update. Where does eclipse store the settings for Navigator View configuration ?

Comment: why do you need them? you won't edit class files.. Eclipse compiles project, it can be executed, packed etc. What's the reason to see them in IDE?